# Bootstrap navbar inconsistent height when logged in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Using the default Jumbotron theme with Django in PTVS, when logged in, all of the templates that I create have more height in the navbar. The text doesn't change, just the bottom margin of the navbar is further down by a few pixels.

The problem doesn't exhibit when:

- The window is shrunk so the navbar shows the hamburger logo
- I copy the exact code from my templates to overwrite a default template without changing the view
- `{% include 'app/loginpartial.html' %}` is removed from `layout.html`
- `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` is removed from `loginpartial.html`
- I browse the problematic pages while logged out

I tried copying the view code from a default, but that didn't fix the problem. Any idea what/where is the problem, and how can it be fixed? Thank you!

**Update** Here's the code within `loginpartial.html` causing the problem, it seems to only affect pages that I've created and not the default pages:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="navbar-brand">{{ user.username }}</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
```

---

`views.py` old

```
def places(request):
    places = Place.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/places.html',     {'title':'Places','places':places,'year':datetime.now().year})
```

`views.py` attempted unsuccessful fix

```
def places(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/places.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Places',
            'places':places,
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

`loginpartial.html` unchanged from default afaik

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form id="logoutForm" action="/logout" method="post" class="navbar-right">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="navbar-brand">{{ user.username }}</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>

</form>

{% else %}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Looks like some additional elements are appearing in DOM as you logged in at site. Have you inspected the page source to find if there are any differencies for logged in user and guest, which may be the reason?

Comment: I don't know how to do that... In Inpsect Element, clicking on the extended part of the navbar while it is highlighted brings me to `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">`, what should I be looking for?

Comment: When I delete `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`, it fixes it. There are two `<li>` inside, one for Username one for Log Off, both need to be deleted for it to fix the height. Does this mean that the css for "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" is wrong? Where is this css stored?

Comment: What changes do you exactly do in loginpartial.html to make your navbar looks as you wish? Removing the whole user.is_authenticated block?

Comment: Yes, removing the user.is_authenticated block fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you get the problem because of the next two things:

1. `navbar-right` class used twice in `user.is_authenticated` block. This class is used to set the position of navbar. To make other elements float right you should use `pull-right` class. So, try to delete this class from the form.
2. Moreover, why is `<ul>` wrapped with the form? Form is just a part of your navbar, so it should be inside the navbar. I'd recommend to use a `<div>` as a navbar holder in your case and to place `<ul>` and `<form>` (if you need it) inside it.

Comment: Thank you!! Deleting that worked! So it is now `<form id="logoutForm" action="/logout" method="post">` 

I also tried moving the `<ul>` outside, but that caused the "Log off" to display weirdly like a normal blue underlined link.

Comment: By the way, this was a problem with the default `loginpartial.html` from Django which was automatically installed by PTVS, you could tell them and get credit for fixing this problem if you want :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I did some more experimenting because I still don't quite understand why it works, and it turns out that if I don't use the Django template for the layout (but rather copy it in manually), it works perfectly without changing any code at all. I also noticed that deleting the `navbar-right` class previously left the body container misaligned as if the navbar was still extended, but the extended part was just invisible. Really weird... I guess I will copy all layout changes to this page manually and forgo the template feature.